# Still cannot watch Netflix on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: netflix

Here is my version of chrome:
Version 49.0.2623.87 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
I read that if I had a version after 37 I was fine. I am not. When I try to play a video I get the screen telling me the requirements.
How do I fix this so I can see netflix?

Comment: Check `chrome://components` (put in the address bar) and make sure that the `widevine` component is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't updated your packages

Open a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I haven't used Ubuntu "apt-get" in a while but I believe this is what you do.

You should also make sure you don't have any extensions blocking certain things.

Let me know if this works